# Using parameters in a SSRS Query

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, parameters

Using SQL Server Report Builder with Visual Studio 2012, I'm trying to do a simple query with a @myDate variable in it something like (there might be error in it but I just wrote it up real quick, real query does not have error :D )

```
Select * from myTable x 
inner join OtherTable y on x.Id = y.Id 
where x.date = @myDate or y.date = @myDate
```

So when I use this, I need to create the parameter for it set the name and the value of the parameter, so it would be @myDate and his value would be equal to 
 `=Parameters!myDate.Value`.
I want it to be visible so I can change it at any time to query different date which will sort different data from my table.
So I could set a default value but that's not the problem.

The problem I am encountering is when I run the report, it ask me the date I want to set as parameter. I enter a date and then it crashes.

Here's what the error says :

SQL0206 : The column or the global variable @MYDATE is unfindable. Cause...:@MYDATE was not found as a column of the table *N in *N and was not found as a global variable...etc

So after this error I tried to add

```
DECLARE @myDate as DATE
```

But that didn't work either..

So do any of you ever did something like this? Should I try something different?

Thanks for taking the time to help a newbie!

---------------Edit---------------

Code for type mismatch

```
Select * from myTable x 
inner join OtherTable y on x.Id = y.Id 
where Date(x.date) = ? or Date(y.date) = ?
```

So when you create a query like this in a SSRS dataset, it will prompt you to identify the parameters. So I had created 1 parameter of type Date/Time (only type of date available in SSRS) and in the query properties I set both ? to value : [@DateParameter]

So the problem now is the data overflow when comparing the SSRS Date/Time type to database Date type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found one way to it. You have to use an expression for the query.

so

```
="Select * from myTable x 
inner join OtherTable y on x.Id = y.Id 
where Date(x.date) = &" Parameters!MyDate.Value " & 
or Date(y.date) = & " Parameters!MyDate.Value " &"
```

That's my query. Now I had to give a value to my Parameter, so I created another dataset which had this query in it :

```
SELECT CURRENT TIMESTAMP
FROM   sysibm.sysdummy1
```

And then with this I had a time, I only needed to format it to my need so I added a column with an expression like this :

```
=Cdate(Left(Cdate(DateSerial(cdate(Left(Fields!Date_Filter.Value,10)).Year, 
cdate(Left(Fields!Date_Filter.Value,10)).Month, 
cdate(Left(Fields!Date_Filter.Value, 10)).Day)), 10))
```

And then I set my parameter's default value to this dataset's column. And then it worked just fine!

Comment: Be careful with this, the `& Parameters!MyDate.Value` method makes your reports vulnerable to SQL injection if the parameter is a free-form string entry!

Answer (score 2):

Try to declare it as a global variable as @@myDate

Comment: It is not working, but I found something I could do. I created 1 date parameter and my 3 query parameters on this single SSRS date parameter. It seems to work. :P

Comment: sweet :)
I'm pretty new to the game, worked on SQL daily for 3 years but only started my formal training course...

Comment: Only problem is the type between date in the database and the date picked. If I use input as string it works perfectly but as soon as I choose DateTime type it creates a data overflow...so I'm having problem cast/converting at the moment